# Office Web Apps - Excel Web App causing errors

Tags: ms-office, office365

I recently managed to get Office Web apps configured with my sharepoint dev environment and am having this issue with just excel documents.

When I create or edit an excel document in the browser, I get the error:

"We're not able to contact the server. It might not be responding, or your internet connection may have been interrupted. Please try again."

Vague I know. Looking at the error from the event viewer below, does anyone have an idea as to what is causing it?

This is the error in the event viewer:

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 9/29/2015 3:03:19 PM 
Event time (UTC): 9/29/2015 10:03:19 PM 
Event ID: 65630219f0764564b0a4e52ee555ec99 
Event sequence: 6 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/x-1-130880377864550895 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /x 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\ExcelServicesWfe\ 
    Machine name: OWASRV01

Process information: 
    Process ID: 13108 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetRangeContent'.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://owa.jacos.com/x/_vti_bin/DynamicGridContent.json/GetRangeContent?context={"SessionId":"32.2063a84ba0ce4808b8b7b98ee4328ce51.D86.1.V22.49w26ovr5nZhddfeEjwQWL14.5.en-US5.en-US32.39b9de68102e4682b580c274004a6a841.S1.N","TransientEditSessionToken":null,"PermissionFlags":786367,"Configurations":1585936,"CompleteResponseTimeout":0,"CollaborationParameter":{"CollaborationState":{}},"ExcelFeatures":1515932864734,"WorkbookMetadataParameter":{"WorkbookMetadataState":{"MetadataVersion":0,"ServerEventVersion":0}},"MachineCluster":null,"AjaxOptions":0}&ewaControlId="m_excelWebRenderer_ewaCtl_m_ewa"&currentObject="Sheet1"&namedObjectViewData={"Mode":1,"Settings":2}&row=28&column=30&rowCount=28&columnCount=30&blockX=1&blockY=1&revision=1&renderingOptions=0 
    Request path: /x/_vti_bin/DynamicGridContent.json/GetRangeContent 
    User host address: 10.22.250.153 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Is this a coding problem or you're just trying to create a spreadsheet without any code?

Comment: Its a configuration problem. I have an office web apps farm that im trying to get to work with sharepoint. Word, powerpoint and onenote docs are created without issue but excel docs give that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error related to the service account of the Excel Web service App not set properly. Set/Configure the service account for the office Excel web service app and recycle the app pools in your dev farm. The current settings is using "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" account.

Comment: I deleted and recreated the excel service app and changed the app pool to the default app pool, and no luck.